# Firegento - add custom attribute field to product in order PDF

Tags: product, product-attribute, pdf

I'm starting to use firegento, but I need to add a particular attribute field, only to the order document, in particular it is the original product code, so I can send my order document directly to the supplier that can read directly this one to understand which product I need. How can I do that?